# Set image src using javascript return value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the image src by using a text returned by a JavaScript function. What is the correct way to assign JavaScript  return value to src?  Code below:

What I am trying to achieve here is adding a dummy random number to the end of the url in order to get rid of browser image caching.

```
<body><div class="slideshow" style="position: absolute;">   
<img src="eval(getMyLink())" width="1024" height="768" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 0; width: 1024px; height: 768px;" title=""> 
<img src="eval(getMyLink())" width="1024" height="768" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 0; width: 1024px; height: 768px;" title=""> 
</div>

<script language="javascript"><!--
    bmi_SafeAddOnload(bmi_load, "bmi_orig_img", 0);//-->
    function getMyLink() {
        var a = "./Files/1.jpg?a=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        return a;
    }
</script></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jQuery.  You will need to add an id attribute to your img tag but this should do it.

```
<img id="imgLink1" width="1024" height="768" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 0; width: 1024px; height: 768px;" title=""> 

$().ready(function(){ $('#imgLink1').att('src', getMyLink()); });
```

Comment: There's no reason to import a huge library just for this.

Comment: Okay, don't use jQuery then.  Just don't use inline js either.

Comment: @GregDzezinski: +1, Thanks. But actually what I want to do is assign src in the img tag itself. I am using JQeury and that's why it has been tagged. Sorry for the downvote you had got from someone who didn't understand tags.

Answer (score -1):

My advices : avoid inline JS, use CSS, and use JQuery.

I would do like this :

```
<body>
    <div class="slideshow" style="position: absolute;">
        <img id="img1" src="" class="myImages" title="image">
        <img id="img2" src="" class="myImages" title="image">
    </div>
    <script>

        bmi_SafeAddOnload(bmi_load, "bmi_orig_img", 0);

        function getMyLink() {
            var a = "./Files/1.jpg?a=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
            return a;
        }

        //Assign image source and display it (you have defined display:none attribute)
        $('#img1').attr('src', getMyLink()).fadeIn(300);
        $('#img2').attr('src', getMyLink()).fadeIn(300);
    </script>

    <style>
        .myImages {
            width : 1024px;
            height : 768px;
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0px; 
            left: 0px; 
            display: none; 
            z-index: 5; 
            opacity: 0;
       }
    </style>
</body>
```

Comment: the relevant HTML elements are loaded above, the structure of the document is clear here: is the .ready() really needed?

Comment: JQuery was tagged when I have written this answer. I think that it is a good exemple to implement that kind of behavior.

Comment: I was not mentioning the use of jQuery here - but the use of .ready - the body is parsed top to bottom - the elements are in the DOM when the js is executed - therefore the $(document).ready( is pointless for this case.

Comment: You are right, in this case it is not mandatory. I have updated my answer.